Completing a CTE that is being used as a filter in the WHERE clause
I wrote the following code that includes a subquery in the WHERE clause and it works just fine. Then I started looking into CTEs to satisfy the same purpose of filtering the data according to the customer IDs identified. As far as I understand it, CTEs are recommended for this purpose because they keep the code clean and organized. However, I was struggling with completing the CTE because I didn't know what columns I should include in it to join in the final step.
select 
    cus.FirstName as First_Name,
    cus.LastName as Last_Name,
    cus.customerid as Customer_ID,
    prod.name as Product_Name, 
    prod.ProductID as Product_ID,
    prod.ProductCategoryID as Product_Category_ID
from saleslt.SalesOrderHeader hd  
left join saleslt.SalesOrderDetail sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
left join saleslt.customer cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
left join saleslt.product prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
where cus.customerid NOT IN (select 
                                min(cus.customerid) as Customer_ID
                            from saleslt.SalesOrderHeader hd  
                            left join saleslt.SalesOrderDetail sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
                            left join saleslt.customer cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
                            left join saleslt.product prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
                            where prod.productcategoryid in ('5','6','7')
                            group by cus.customerid
                            )
ORDER BY cus.FirstName, cus.LastName

;WITH test as (
select min(cus.customerid) as Customer_ID
from saleslt.SalesOrderHeader hd  
left join saleslt.SalesOrderDetail sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = 
sod.SalesOrderID
left join saleslt.customer cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
left join saleslt.product prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
where prod.productcategoryid in ('5','6','7')
group by cus.customerid
)
select 
    cus.FirstName as First_Name,
    cus.LastName as Last_Name,
    cus.customerid as Customer_ID,
    prod.name as Product_Name, 
    prod.ProductID as Product_ID,
    prod.ProductCategoryID as Product_Category_ID
from saleslt.SalesOrderHeader hd  
left join saleslt.SalesOrderDetail sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
left join saleslt.customer cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
left join saleslt.product prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
left join test t ON t.??? = ???
where cus.customerid NOT IN test.customerID

The point of the query is to exclude customers in the final query if they were included in the CTE. How should I complete the join and query overall?

LEFT JOIN test t ON cus.customerid = t.customer_id WHERE t.customer_id IS NULL

This question is similar to: Return row only if value doesn't exist. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The NOT IN operator still needs either an explicit list or a subquery. Try where cus.customerid NOT IN (select t.customerID from test t).

@T N This makes sense. I totally forgot you can throw in a select query in the where clause.

@Meditation As per the conversation in comments, hope your issue is resolved. Putting it as a solution with example for others searching for similar issue on SO.

To use a CTE for filtering out specific customer IDs, you can apply a LEFT JOIN along with a NULL check.
Suppose I added some new customers with orders for products in a different category, such as ProductCategoryID = 8. In this example, one customer, Alice Brown, didn’t purchase any products from categories 5, 6, or 7. Therefore, she won’t appear in the ExcludedCustomers CTE and will show up in the final results.

In the output below, you can see that the ExcludedCustomers CTE successfully filtered out all customers who bought products in the excluded categories, allowing only Alice Brown to be displayed.
;WITH ExcludedCustomers AS (
    SELECT MIN(cus.CustomerID) AS Customer_ID
    FROM saleslt.SalesOrderHeader AS hd
    LEFT JOIN saleslt.SalesOrderDetail AS sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
    LEFT JOIN saleslt.Customer AS cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN saleslt.Product AS prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    WHERE prod.ProductCategoryID IN (5, 6, 7)
    GROUP BY cus.CustomerID
)
SELECT 
    cus.FirstName AS First_Name,
    cus.LastName AS Last_Name,
    cus.CustomerID AS Customer_ID,
    prod.Name AS Product_Name, 
    prod.ProductID AS Product_ID,
    prod.ProductCategoryID AS Product_Category_ID
FROM saleslt.SalesOrderHeader AS hd
LEFT JOIN saleslt.SalesOrderDetail AS sod ON hd.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
LEFT JOIN saleslt.Customer AS cus ON cus.CustomerID = hd.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN saleslt.Product AS prod ON prod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
LEFT JOIN ExcludedCustomers AS ec ON cus.CustomerID = ec.Customer_ID
WHERE ec.Customer_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY cus.FirstName, cus.LastName;



reference- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
